# Can I link to a .txt file in a way that prevents browsers from treating it like html?

Tags: browser, quirks-mode, plaintext

Since a while, when I open a plain text file with long lines, the lines will break.

See this example: https://oeis.org/A195665/a195665_4.txt

In Firebug I can see, that the text is in `<pre>` tags in an html structure.

To avoid the line breaks, I have to click on "View Page Source".

Is there any server side way to prevent that?

Comment: Browsers are made to show formatted text. How to show unformatted text is up to the browser (and the preferences of their programmers/ users). If you want (server side) control, add formatting...

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the browser is at fault.  I believe it is the web server's job to serve it up differently.  You should google how to do that for your particular web server.

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with plain text files. They have been around long before browsers even existed, and now browsers treat them like incorrect html. That's at least indecent. I guess there is no way to directly link to the source of a page?

Answer (score 0):

This works in Firefox and Chrome:

```
view-source:http://oeis.org/A195665/a195665_4.txt
```

But not in IE. However, IE doesn't break the lines in the first place.